# Python regex to extract file name from git diff syntax

Tags: python-3.x, regex, bitbucket

I am trying to do some validation for bit bucket commits. I need to extract the file name from the commit text that I get using BitBucket API. The text is in following format

```
---
 src/classes/SVMX_EventTriggerHandler.cls | 653 ++++++++++++++---------
 1 file changed, 400 insertions(+), 253 deletions(-)

diff --git a/src/classes/SVMX_EventTriggerHandler.cls b/src/classes/SVMX_EventTriggerHandler.cls
index 568a6c77ba..51adfeadb0 100644
```

I have currently using following regex (extracted from unidiff library) to extract both the filenames in two groups

```
RE_DIFF_GIT_HEADER = re.compile(
    r'^diff --git (?P<source>(a/)?[^\t\n]+) (?P<target>(b/)?[^\t\n]+)')
```

This works correctly. I get two groups one with **a** and the other with **b**.

**Source group:** a/src/classes/SVMX_EventTriggerHandler.cls

**Target group:** b/src/classes/SVMX_EventTriggerHandler.cls

But some of the files have spaces in their name

```
diff --git a/src/profiles/EU Customer Care Advisor.profile b/src/profiles/EU Customer Care
```

and this regex fails in this scenario. I get source group as

**Source Group:** a/src/profiles/EU Customer Care Advisor.profile b/src/profiles/EU Customer

**Target Group:** Care

I want to have regex that can work in both cases.

Comment: Can you get the filenames from the API somehow? That would be safest of all.

Comment: I have checked. The only way to get info on files is to actually get the patch detail which provides the complete file content.

Comment: Are you forced to read existing `git diff` output? If not, consider using `git diff --name-status` first, or `git diff --raw` first, and only then reading `git diff` output—or read the files from the commits directly and use Python's `difflib` if you need individual diffs. (Why read from the Bitbucket API when you can clone the repository?) I snipped the [tag:git] tag on the assumption that you are in fact stuck with this; if not, put it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the files start with `a/` or `b/` how about:

- [`^diff --git (?<source>a\/.+)\s(?<target>b\/.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/OegT7X/1)

[image]

`.+` isn't the most precise way to get the filename of course -- and maybe you can replace that with the acceptable chars, such as [`[\w.\/ ]+`](https://regex101.com/r/Kvqwtk/1), but it should serve as a good start for you.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation for the rule. Based on my knowledge I assume we are saying starting with a/ match everything till the space and this means the first group should have till EU but it working as I expect. So some explanation would help me in better understanding

Comment: @Neel yes that's close! But it gets everything until ```<space>b/```, so a space followed by a "b" followed by a slash. Does that make sense?